# In-Place Editing troubles

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

i would like to create in-place editing for something and i would like to start off with creating a div that has text which can be edited... but i'm facing an issue:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of null
```

here is my code:

```
var node = dojo.createElement("div");
node.setAttribute("id", "ieb");


var area = new Textarea(); 

var newContent = document.createTextNode("When you click on this div you'll be able to edit it (in plain text).The editor's size will initially match the size of the (original) text, but will expand/contract as you type.");

node.appendChild(newContent);
var eb = new InlineEditBox({
    editor: area,
    autoSave: false
}, "ieb");
```

what am i doing wrong here? or what am i missing?

i was trying to follow a long with this tutorial:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/InlineEditBox.html

thanks in advance... new to dojo..

***EDIT:***
seems like it's going into inlineeditbox.js and breaking on this line: `this.displayNode.setAttribute("role", "button");`

Comment: is  new Textarea(); a dojo thing or an error?

Comment: hello.. it's a dojo thing

Comment: my bad. we see a lot of crap in here, and last time i checked it out, dojo used namespaces. i guess im not up to date on five-year-old javascript monstrosities that never went anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
require(["dojo", "dijit/InlineEditBox", "dijit/form/Textarea"], function (dojo, Textarea, InlineEditBox) {
var node = dojo.create("div", {
    id: "ieb",
    innerHTML: "When you click on this div you'll be able to edit it (in plain text).The editor's size will initially match the size of the (original) text, but will expand/contract as you ty"
}, dojo.body());


var eb = new InlineEditBox({
    editor: Textarea,
    autoSave: false
}, "ieb");

eb.startup();
 });
```

Comment: hi, i found the solution. it was having the id "ieb" ... instead i hade to replate "ieb" with node. this did the trick. thanks anyway :)